# Smart quotations aren't recognized by InStr()

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a code like so:

```
Sub MoveToBeginningSentence()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim selectedWords As Range
    Dim selectedText As String
    Const punctuation As String = " & Chr(145) & "
    On Error GoTo ErrorReport
     ' Cancel macro when there's no text selected

    Selection.Cut
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Set selectedWords = Selection.Range
    selectedText = selectedWords
    If InStr(selectedText, punctuation) = 0 Then
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
        Selection.Paste
    Else
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdSentence, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
        Selection.Paste
        Selection.Paste
        Selection.Paste
        Selection.Paste
    End If

ErrorReport:

End Sub
```

Basically, it help me move whatever text I have selected to the beginning of the sentence in Word. If there's no quotation mark, then paste once. If there is a quote mark, paste 4 times.

The problem is regardless of whether there's any quotation there or not, it will only paste once. If I set the macro to detect any other character, it will work fine. But every single time I try to force it to detect smart quotations, it will fail.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I think that you are pasting over the same spot repeatedly.  Try moving the Selection over by the `Len(selectedText)`

Comment: Why do you surround the smart quotes character - Chr(145) with quotation marks? That's what's being compared. You need those quotation marks for regular characters, such as punction = "." But when you specify a character code you'd usually not want them? I think punctuatoin = Chr(145) is what you need.

Comment: Correction of my previous statement: punctuation is searching literally for the following character combination: & Chr(1415) & My proposed solution remains the same: punctuation = Chr (145)

Comment: @CindyMeister Unless he means `Chr(48) & Chr(145) & Chr(48)` which would result in `"?"` (assuming Chr(145) = ?, I am too lazy to check).

Comment: @Cindy Meister: Without the quotation, I get a "Constant expression is required" error. Do I need to add something else for it to work?

Comment: @user6432984: I want it to paste the same thing 4 times, though, so me pasting repeatedly was intentional. That said, will Len() achieve the same purpose?

Comment: Declare it as a regular variable (Dim), not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the Selection object is always a bit chancy; on the whole, it's better to work with a Range object. You can have only one Selection; you can have as many Ranges as you need.

Because your code uses the Selection object it's not 100% clear what the code does. Based on my best guess, I put together the following example which you can tweak if it's not exactly right.

At the beginning, I check whether there's something in the selection, or it's a blinking insertion point. If no text is selected, the macro ends. This is better than invoking Error handling, then not handling anything: If other problems crop up in your code, you wouldn't know about them.

A Range object is instantiated for the selection - there's no need to "cut" it, as you'll see further along. Based on this, the entire sentence is also assigned to a Range object. The text of the sentence is picked up, then the sentence's Range is "collapsed" to its starting point. (Think of this like pressing the left arrow on the keyboard.)

Now the sentence's text is checked for the character Chr(145). If it's not there, the original selection's text (including formatting) is added at the beginning of the sentence. If it's there, then it's added four times.

Finally, the original selection is deleted.

```
Sub MoveToBeginningSentence()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim selectedText As String
    Dim punctuation As String
    punctuation = Chr(145)  ' ‘ "smart" apostrophe
    Dim selRange As word.Range
    Dim curSentence As word.Range
    Dim i As Long

   ' Cancel macro when there's no text selected
   If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then Exit Sub

    Set selRange = Selection.Range
    Set curSentence = selRange.Sentences(1)
    selectedText = curSentence.Text
    curSentence.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    If InStr(selectedText, punctuation) = 0 Then
        curSentence.FormattedText = selRange.FormattedText
    Else
        For i = 1 To 4
            curSentence.FormattedText = selRange.FormattedText
            curSentence.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Next
    End If
    selRange.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code.

```
Sub MoveToBeginningSentence()
    ' 19 Jan 2018

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim SelText As String
    Dim Repeats As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Selection.Range
        SelText = .Text                     ' copy the selected text
        Set Rng = .Sentences(1)             ' identify the current sentence
    End With

    If Len(SelText) Then                    ' Skip when no text is selected
        With Rng
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Selection.Range.Text = ""       ' delete the selected text
            Repeats = IIf(IsQuote(.Text), 4, 1)
            If Repeats = 4 Then .MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
            For i = 1 To Repeats
                .Text = SelText & .Text
            Next i
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select some text.", _
               vbExclamation, "Selection is empty"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsQuote(Txt As String) As Boolean
    ' 19 Jan 2018

    Dim Quotes
    Dim Ch As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Quotes = Array(34, 147, 148, -24143, -24144)
    Ch = Asc(Txt)
'    Debug.Print Ch                      ' read ASCII code of first character
    For i = 0 To UBound(Quotes)
        If Ch = Quotes(i) Then Exit For
    Next i
    IsQuote = (i <= UBound(Quotes))
End Function
```

The approach taken is to identify the first character of the selected sentence using the ASC() function. For a normal quotation mark that would be 34. In my test I came up with -24143 and -24144 (opening and closing). I couldn't identify Chr(145) but found MS stating that curly quotation marks are Chr(147) and Chr(148) respectively. Therefore I added a function that checks all of them. If you enable the line `Debug.Print Ch` in the function the character code actually found will be printed to the immediate window. You might add more character codes to the array `Quotes`.

The code itself doesn't consider spaces between words. Perhaps Word will take care of that, and perhaps you don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply `InStr` with the starting position as a first parameter:

```
If InStr(1, selectedText, punctuation) = 0 Then
```

Also

```
Const punctuation As String = " & Chr(145) & "
```

is going to search for `space-ampersand-space-Chr(145)-space-ampersand-space`. If you want to search for the smart quote character then use

```
Const punctuation As String = Chr(145)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php) this is not true or required. You only need to specify 1 as the start position if you also require the vbCompareMethod optional argument to be something other than the default.

Comment: I'm getting an error when changing the Const punctuation As String = Chr(145) line. It says Constant expression is required.